# Why does smoke change the shading?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I've rendered the exact same scene with the only difference being that one has smoke, and for some reason it's changing the shading of the objects within the domain. Does anyone know why this is? And more so, how to fix it? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If the smoke is pink, it makes sense that looking through the smoke things are pink.

Comment: @cegaton It’s the faceting of the crater that’s the issue. It’s meant to be smooth like in the image without smoke.

Comment: What changed exactly between the two scenes? How did you make the smoke? Are you sure you didn't change the crater topology, face smoothness, poly count, modifier?

Comment: The smoke was created using the Quick FX thing, and the literally the only difference is that the top one is rendered at frame 120 and the bottom one is frame 0.